# Symfony2/PHP - Issue with array

Tags: php, arrays, symfony

I am trying to move some code into Symfony and for some reason something is not working and I cant work out why.  I have broken my function down so I can identify the issue, infact taken it to the beginning.

So I have

```
public function getAvailabilityData(){
    $alerts = $this->em->getRepository('NickAlertBundle:AvailabilityAlert')->getActiveAlertIds();

    $alertsArray = array();

    if (!$alerts) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Availability.');
    }

    foreach($alerts as $alert){
        $alertId = (int)$alert['id'];
        var_dump($alertId);
        $alertsArray[$alertId] = array();
    }
    var_dump($alertsArray);

    return $alertsArray;
}
```

Now I know I have 2 alerts in my database, and this is further shown when I var_dump $alertId

> int(1) int(2)

So these ids are supposed to be the first element of my array, which is what I do.  But in the var_dump at the end where I output the array, I get an empty array

```
array(2) { 
    [1]=> array(0) { } 
    [2]=> array(0) { } 
}
```

Why would this be?

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to get? The array with all your alert ids?

Comment: To start with yes.  This will end up being a multi dimensional array, but the first element will be the ids.

Comment: Then use `$alertsArray[] = $alertId;` instead of `$alertsArray[$alertId] = array();`

Comment: That will set the id as element 0.  I need to do it the way I am to build up a multi dimensional array.

Comment: You can use any key you want: `$alertsArray['ids'][] = $alertId;`

Answer (score 0):

you explicitly set an empty array as the value

```
foreach($alerts as $alert){
    $alertId = (int)$alert['id'];
    var_dump($alertId);
    $alertsArray[$alertId] = array();
}
```

sound like you want sth like: +

```
foreach($alerts as $alert){
    $alertId = (int)$alert['id'];
    var_dump($alertId);
    $alertsArray[$alertId] = $alertId;
}
```